# Android Studio 1.0.0 - Failed to find butterknife:6.0.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, butterknife

I am using Android Studio 1.0.0. I am trying to add dependencies of butterknife.

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.11'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.2'
}
```

But i am getting the following Gradle error:

Error:Failed to find: com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.0.0

Comment: Show us your entire build.gradle. Where are your repositories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added, below three lines, it got fixed. Thanks everyone.

```
repositories {
     mavenCentral()
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem! Finally, when I tried to clean project I got more specific gradle error: No cached version of com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.0.0 available for offline mode. So the problem was that gradle offline mode was enabled! All you need to do is **uncheck *Settings -> Gradle -> Offline work*** ...

Comment: Or open console and run `gradlew`. That way you doesn't have to resolve online dependencies while building in the studio and save time.

Answer (score 0):

I tried in my `build.gradle`, it works.

In the **root** `build.gradle`. You can try put `repositories { mavenCentral() }` outside the buildscript, then it would work.

**EDIT**

build.gradle in app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.0.0'
}
```

build.gradle in root

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0-rc4'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

settings.gradle

```
include ':app'
```

Comment: Still no luck ... Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project dir.

```
./gradlew clean
```

This downloaded the dependencies and resolved "Failed to find:" dependenices issue